# Ubuntu 12.04 Apache2 Virtual Host Port *.80 Not Working

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu

I have been trying to resolve this for 4 days to no avail. Please Help!

The problem is very simple - my SSL port 443 is working and loading my Symfony site (https://mysite.com) but my port 80 is not working and is loading a could not connect to mysite.com error in all browsers.

I'm running a LAMP on Ubuntu 12.04LTS / apache2 / MYSQL / PHP5.

Virtual hosts are enabled and when I run "apache2ctl -S" I get:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
    *:80                   mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default.conf:1)
    *:443                  mysite.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:1)
```

My Virtual Host files (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled) are:
1) default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/Symfony/web
</VirtualHost>
```

2) mysite.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@mysite.com
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/Symfony/web
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/Symfony/web>
                AllowOverride None

                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [QSA,L]
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/ssl_access.log combined

        Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
        <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
        </Directory>

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/mysite.com/mysite.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/mysite.com/mysite.com.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/mysite.com/mysite.com.ca-bundle
        <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </FilesMatch>
        <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Is apache actually listening on port 80? Do you have any iptables rules in place?

Comment: Yep is listening - ran "sudo netstat -ntlp | grep :80" and got:
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      46356/apache2

Comment: Not sure about iptalbes - can you elaborate for me?

Comment: Mate - you are a superstar. HTTP was not open in the iptables - I ran the following to open it up:
"sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT" and it worked straight away. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might have a firewall rule blocking that port.

Comment: Correct thank you - as in the comments above I noticed HTTP was not receiving inputs - so I ran the following and it worked straight away:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT